How to Exclude Post by ID from Category using Query Arguments in WordPress
I'm attempting to edit the following theme file. I'd like to exclude a certain number of posts from the Category Query arguments.
Any idea how I can go about doing that? Just need guidance on which part of the theme code I should change to exclude the desired posts:
// Query args.
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => apply_filters( 'my_theme_related_blog_posts_count', absint( get_theme_mod( 'my_theme_blog_related_count', '3' ) ) ),
    'orderby'        => 'DESC',
    'post__not_in'   => array( get_the_ID() ),
    'no_found_rows'  => true,
    'tax_query'      => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'post-format-quote', 'post-format-link' ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),
);

// If category.
if ( 'category' === $term_tax ) {
    $args['category__in'] = $terms_ids;
}



Add them to the array that gets specified for post__not_in ...?

@CBroe So something like this: array( get_the_ID(), 2, 3, 4, 5 )

From my understanding you want to exclude current post from related posts ?

@Snuffy current and post 2, 3, 4 and 5.

'post__not_in'   => array( get_the_ID(),2,3,4,5 ), should be fine.

    // Query args.
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => apply_filters('my_theme_related_blog_posts_count', absint(get_theme_mod('my_theme_blog_related_count', '3'))),
    'orderby'        => 'DESC',
    'post__not_in'   => array(get_the_ID()), // Exclude the current post
    'no_found_rows'  => true,
    'tax_query'      => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array('post-format-quote', 'post-format-link'),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),
);

// If category.
if ('category' === $term_tax) {
    $args['category__in'] = $terms_ids;

    // Add the following line to exclude specific post IDs
    $posts_exclude = array(); // empty array for storing post ids
    if (isset($args['post__not_in']) && !empty($args['post__not_in'])) {
        $posts_exclude = $args['post__not_in'];
    }

    $posts_exclude = array_merge($posts_exclude, array(1, 2, 3)); // Replace 1, 2, 3 with the IDs of the posts you want to exclude
    $args['post__not_in'] = $posts_exclude;
}


Initialized an empty array $posts_exclude before checking if there are already posts to exclude.
If there are posts to exclude ($args['post__not_in'] is set and not
empty), I assign its value to $posts_exclude.
Then, I merge the additional post IDs (array(1, 2, 3)) with $posts_exclude.
Finally, I assign the merged array back to $args['post__not_in'].

